# How to implement audio effects like 3D surround sound and reverb in javafx

Tags: audio, javafx, effect

I have developed a music player in javafx.
Is there any way to implement 3D audio effect similar to WOW EFFECT in windows media player.
I have searched there is no method of mediaplayer to implement such thing.

My javafx level: intermediate

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the only effect that can be applied on the JavaFX MediaPlayer is an equalizer, with the `javafx.scene.media.AudioEqualizer` class. You can get the `MediaPlayer`'s `AudioEqualizer` with the getAudioEqualizer method, and modify its existing bands, add/remove bands, etc.

However, if you want to implement other effects (reverb, delay, distortion... whatever else), I think you're out of luck: The JavaFX media API doesn't provide methods for that, and it doesn't seem to be meant to be extensible in any way (you can't add support for other codecs either, for example).

If you need more than what the JavaFX media API provides, the only solution for serious media playback in java seems to be to use a native library with a Java wrapper. vlcj ([website here](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/index.html), [Javadoc here](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.0.0/)) seems to be a good solution: it offers a java wrapper around VLC, which is a really powerful media player, so you should be able to do most of what you may want - worst case, it provides APIs to directly access the audio buffer and manipulate it yourself. It's clearly quite a bit more involved than using JavaFX's native media playback though...